# What is the maximum number of system administrator can be created in developer sandbox

Tags: profile, sandbox, system-admin

What is the maximum number of system administrator can be created in developer sandbox?

We already have 22 System administrator (profile) created in the sandbox.

When I was trying to create a new System administrator, I am not getting the option from Profile drop down as System administrator (please check attached screen shot).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Developer Edition Org or an actual Developer Sandbox from a Production Org? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You have clearly run out of SF licences as it is not appearing in the dropdown.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev
Yes, its an actual Developer Sandbox from a Production Org.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set everyone as administrator, if you want to, and you can create as many active users as you have licenses (Setup > Company Profile > Company Information). Most likely, you don't have any free licenses at the moment.

Comment: In fact. If you look at the top of his screenshot, that is exactly the case.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox 
Nice to see your comment. Yes you are right. Remaining license for Salesforce=0. But license is available for others (Salesforce Platform, Chatter Free, Chatter External).
Is it possible to create System Admin using these users?

Comment: @Robi No, only Salesforce users can be a System Administrator. You'll have to deactivate another user before you can set up a new System Administrator.